# Unity - How to set the color of an individual face when clicking a mesh?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Yesterday others on Stack Overflow helped me determine [how to recolor a mesh triangle to red by clicking on it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57405631/7111561), it works great, the only problem is that the 3 vertices that get recolored are shared between triangles. This results in coloration that looks rather smeared. I'm really hoping there's a way to color only a single face (or normal if you will).

I've attached the following script to my mesh that uses a raycast to determine the surface coordinate and translate a green cube there. The gif below will better illustrate this problem.

Once again, any help or insight into this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyRayDraw : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cube;
    private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    Mesh mesh;
    Vector3[] vertices;
    Color[] colorArray;

    private void Start()
    {
        mesh = transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        vertices = mesh.vertices;

        colorArray = new Color[vertices.Length];
        for (int k = 0; k < vertices.Length; k++)
        {
            colorArray[k] = Color.white;
        }
        mesh.colors = colorArray;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
            {
                Snap(hit.point); // Moves the green cube

                int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
                var vertIndex1 = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 0];
                var vertIndex2 = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 1];
                var vertIndex3 = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 2];

                colorArray[vertIndex1] = Color.red;
                colorArray[vertIndex2] = Color.red;
                colorArray[vertIndex3] = Color.red;

                mesh.colors = colorArray;                
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("no hit");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: As said coloring is done by vertecis not by triangles or faces. The only solution would be to make sure that triangles don't share vertices... It works e.g. with a cube primitive because that one uses a mesh were there are individual vertices for each triangle .. other then e.g. the sphere in our example ;)

Comment: You need to check if other faces (tris in this case) refer the same vertex. If so, copy the vertex to create an independend face. Otherwise the neighbour face will interpolate the vertex colors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you say the issue is that the vertices are shared between triangles but coloring is always vertex based.

The idea for a solution is:

- for each vertex of the hit triangle check if it is used by other triangles
- if so copy its position to create a new separated vertex
- update the triangle to use the newly created vertex indices
- (evtl.) use `RecalculateNormals` to make the triangles face outside without having to care about the order of provided vertices

```c#
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyRayDraw : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cube;

    // Better to reference those already in the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private MeshFilter meshFilter;
    [SerializeField] private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    [SerializeField] private MeshCollider meshCollider;

    private Mesh _mesh;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!meshFilter) meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        if (!meshRenderer) meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        if (!meshCollider) meshCollider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();

        _mesh = meshFilter.mesh;

        // create new colors array where the colors will be created
        var colors = new Color[_mesh.vertices.Length];
        for (var k = 0; k < colors.Length; k++)
        {
            colors[k] = Color.white;
        }
        _mesh.colors = colors;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) return;

        var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.triangleIndex);
            //cube.transform.position = hit.point;

            // Get current vertices, triangles and colors
            var vertices = _mesh.vertices;
            var triangles = _mesh.triangles;
            var colors = _mesh.colors;

            // Get the vert indices for this triangle
            var vert1Index = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 0];
            var vert2Index = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 1];
            var vert3Index = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 2];

            // Get the positions for the vertices
            var vert1Pos = vertices[vert1Index];
            var vert2Pos = vertices[vert2Index];
            var vert3Pos = vertices[vert3Index];

            // Now for all three vertices we first check if any other triangle if using it
            // by simply count how often the indices are used in the triangles list
            var vert1Occurrences = 0;
            var vert2Occurrences = 0;
            var vert3Occurrences = 0;
            foreach (var index in triangles)
            {
                if (index == vert1Index) vert1Occurrences++;
                else if (index == vert2Index) vert2Occurrences++;
                else if (index == vert3Index) vert3Occurrences++;
            }

            // Create copied Lists so we can dynamically add entries
            var newVertices = vertices.ToList();
            var newColors = colors.ToList();

            // Now if a vertex is shared we need to add a new individual vertex
            // and also an according entry for the color array
            // and update the vertex index
            // otherwise we will simply use the vertex we already have
            if (vert1Occurrences > 1)
            {
                newVertices.Add(vert1Pos);
                newColors.Add(new Color());
                vert1Index = newVertices.Count - 1;
            }

            if (vert2Occurrences > 1)
            {
                newVertices.Add(vert2Pos);
                newColors.Add(new Color());
                vert2Index = newVertices.Count - 1;
            }

            if (vert3Occurrences > 1)
            {
                newVertices.Add(vert3Pos);
                newColors.Add(new Color());
                vert3Index = newVertices.Count - 1;
            }

            // Update the indices of the hit triangle to use the (eventually) new
            // vertices instead
            triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 0] = vert1Index;
            triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 1] = vert2Index;
            triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 2] = vert3Index;

            // color these vertices
            newColors[vert1Index] = Color.red;
            newColors[vert2Index] = Color.red;
            newColors[vert3Index] = Color.red;

            // write everything back
            _mesh.vertices = newVertices.ToArray();
            _mesh.triangles = triangles;
            _mesh.colors = newColors.ToArray();

            _mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("no hit");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

Note, however, that this works with simple coloring but might not for complex textures with UV mapping. You would have to also update the `mesh.uv` if using UV mapped textures.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for clearly illustrating how to duplicate the shared vertices. My understanding of mesh data has greatly increased as a result of this. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, just one more question - If I want to colorize UVs would I simply need to follow the same pattern as vertices and copy those coordinates when adding them in like this?
```...
            if (vert1Occurrences > 1)
            {
                newVertices.Add(vert1Pos);
                newColors.Add(new Color());
                newUVs.Add(new Vector2(vert1Pos.x, vert1Pos.y));
                vert1Index = newVertices.Count - 1;
            }
...
```

I think I'm close, but maybe missing something.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I figured it out! Simply needed to copy positions from the original mesh.uv array using the same vertex indices, and then add those into a new UV list in exactly the same manner as you demonstrated with vertices using their original positions. Finally, assign it back to the mesh. Thanks a million!