# IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. MyRayDraw.Update () (at Assets/MyRayDraw.cs:37)

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am trying to write a debugging tool for unity where I can select the face of triangle i am facing using RayCast.hittriangleIndex. But I am confused I am getting index out of bound error.

The complete code is below. I have also attached screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApIiJ.png)

```
`
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyRayDraw : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cube;
    private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    Mesh mesh;
    Vector3[] vertices;
    Color[] colorArray;

    private void Start()
    {
        mesh = transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        vertices = mesh.vertices;

        // create new colors array where the colors will be created
        colorArray = new Color[vertices.Length];
        for (int k = 0; k < vertices.Length; k++)
        {
            colorArray[k] = Color.white;
        }
        mesh.colors = colorArray;
    }

    void Update()
    {        
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
            {
               int [] triangles = mesh.triangles;

                var vertIndex1 = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 0];
                var vertIndex2 = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 1];
                var vertIndex3 = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 2];

                colorArray[vertIndex1] = Color.red;
                colorArray[vertIndex2] = Color.red;
                colorArray[vertIndex3] = Color.red;

                mesh.colors = colorArray;
                
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("no hit");
            }
        }
    }
}
`
```

When I am trying to select the face of triangle. I am getting indexoutofbound error. I rechecked the error but could not found a solution for it.  I also checked here [Unity - How to use mesh triangleIndex to recolor a triangle when clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405631/unity-how-to-use-mesh-triangleindex-to-recolor-a-triangle-when-clicked) but was not helpful for me.

Comment: Use a breakpoint after you create the array and check the length of your array it might be empty.

Comment: I'd suggest to edit the question and add a Tag for the programming language (`[c#]`?)